# Semidirect product of point stabiliser and regular normal subgroup.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, normal-subgroups, semidirect-product

Why is it that a permutation group $G$ on $\Omega$ with regular normal subgroup $K$ is a split extension (internal semidirect product) of $K$ and  the point stabiliser $G_\alpha$ for some $\alpha\in\Omega$?

I can see the intersection of the two subgroups is trivial by regularity of $K$. I know there is an action by conjugation of the stabiliser on $K$.

But could you explain why $G$ is $K\cdot G_\alpha$ where $\cdot$ is the product of subsets of a group?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take an arbitrary element $g\in G$.  Since $K$ is transitive, therefore, there is an element $k\in K$ for which $\alpha^g = \alpha^k$.  Hence, $\alpha^{k^{-1}g}=\alpha$, that is, $k^{-1}g\in G_\alpha$, so $g\in KG_\alpha$. Since $g$ was arbitary, it follows that $G\leq KG_\alpha$ and, as the reverse inclusion is obvious, we have $G = KG_\alpha$.